# Visual Studio 2012 以降のマクロ機能

Tags: visual-studio

以前の Visual Studio には、テキスト編集などの一連の操作を記録（<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>）して、実行（<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>）できるマクロ機能があり、それなりに重宝していたのですが、[こちらの記事](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/fdotnet/special/vs2012review/vs2012review_02.html)によると、 Visual Studio 2012 以降では削除されてしまったようです。

拡張機能などで類似した機能を提供しているものはあるでしょうか？
Visual Studio Community 2013 で利用可能なものがあれば教えてください。

Comment: 全然関係ないですけど kbd タグ、良いですね!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoftのチームから、Macros for Visual Studio 2013 というものが出ているようです。
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d3fbf133-e51b-41a2-b86f-9560a96ff62b

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2013 で使用できました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Platform Team提供のもの以外では下記があるようです。

Text Macros for Visual Studio 2012/2013
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e2103b6-87cf-4fef-9410-a580c434b602

英語版Stackoverflowの同様の質問内でも紹介されていたようです。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062515/can-i-record-play-macros-in-visual-studio-2012-2013